# Join load data infile with select statment

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

I would like to know if there is a way to use the query LOAD DATA INFILE with a union statement. Basically, I have two statements one select statement and I one LOAD DATA INFILE I would like to join the two statement together in one query. Is there anyway to do this??

What I would like to do something similar to

```
select * from news where id>=1 UNION LOAD DATA INFILE '/test' into table test;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to do this??

No.

Comment: Any sources that support this and why No??

Comment: Just because such a query makes not a little sense.

Comment: The answer met all the requirements of effective communication - accuracy, relevance, clarity, and brevity.

Comment: @YourCommonSense if there is no technical proof then every thing is possible !!